# C# Generic method that can infer its type argument from expression parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface, type-inference

I am attempting to create a method, that can accept a type of an object as a type parameter, and a reference to one of the object's properties, along with its type. Something like so:

`service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Ticks)`.

I looked at how other libraries were doing such things, and ended up with the following definition:

```
interface IService
{
    void DoWork<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> propertySelector);
}
```

Ideally, a user can pass in a type of an object, and then "select" each of its properties with an expression. My method can then know the **expression selected**, along with **its type** and the **type of the object**.

```
  service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Ticks);
  service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.TimeOfDay);
  service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Second);
```

However, calling the method this way results in the following error:

```
Using the generic method 'IService.DoWork<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>>)' requires 2 type arguments
```

If I specfiy the type of the property, then everything works fine:

```
  service.DoWork<DateTime, long>(dt => dt.Ticks);
  service.DoWork<DateTime, TimeSpan>(dt => dt.TimeOfDay);
  service.DoWork<DateTime, int>(dt => dt.Second);
```

**BUT**, this seems really redundant. The compiler can extract the type from the expression argument that I have provided, and as far as I know a lot of other libraries use such type inferring to provide clean interfaces (Linq, MOQ, FluentAssertions to name a few)

I imagine i need to somehow change my method definition, but I can't seem to find a correct way to do it.

PS: Here is the complete code snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace GenericTypeInterface
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IService service = null;

            service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Ticks);
            service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.TimeOfDay);
            service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Second);
        }
    }

    interface IService
    {
        void DoWork<TObject, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> propertySelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Type inference works all or nothing, you cannot specify one parameter and let the compiler guess all the others. If DoWork hast two parameters, you specify either both or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let it "infer" both generic arguments by writing explicitly the type of the lambda parameter:

```
service.DoWork((DateTime dt) => dt.Ticks);
```

Comment: Nice, this would work.

However, I am really hoping to find a way where I do not need to cast the input param.

I really want to retain the `service.DoWork<DateTime>(dt => dt.Ticks)`

Comment: There is no other way, you define a new variable here, nobody, besides you, knows it should be a DateTime. Maybe it's clearer to you, if you use x instead of dt.

Comment: @Kobek There is no casting involved at all. This is simply specifying the type of the parameter of the lambda expression, which is part of the syntax of lambda expressions - It is optional specify a type for the parameters of lambda expressions. It is impossible to do it the way you want, because, `DoWork` has 2 generic parameters, and you must either specify both or none of them. You can't let the compiler infer _some_ of the generic arguments. Maybe this'll be a feature in the future, but not now.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll see if I can rewrite my interface to have a way of omitting both of the params